# normalise data and draw a graph

Tags: excel, graph

i have a data as:

13880.23

6056.203

9311.61

7866.84

2206.36

1831.2

11293.25

5762.053

7996.76

14815.93

11838.63

17314.97

17998.97

800.07

2598.04

8223.87

9669.02

7596.847

233.47

82.2

-24.42

-76.52

-161.84

949.8

-276.28

-377.83

-325.57

these are the energies of files 1 to 27 in an order. i have to draw a graph in excel sheet but since the energy varies from 13880 to -325, graph will be either too large or will not show values properly. Can a method be possible to bring these values in a particular range and then plot a graph? how can i do this?

Comment: Depends, what are you trying to show/highlight with your graph?

Answer (score 1):

Perform some function that will normalize the values, like logarithm or square root (where's possible - non-negative numbers only)

Comment: +1 or plot abs(negatives) in a different series on the same graph logarithmically.